# Symfony3: Best Pratice to get Status property translated on Twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation

Suppose a simple Symfony `Product Entity` like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table(name="product")
*/
class Product
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
     private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
     private $status;

}
```

The status will be stored on the DataBase as Integer, and each integer will correspond with a human readable value:

0 => Deleted 
1 => Active 
2 => Disabled 
...

When I display a Product on Twig, I need to display this human readable status String, and I should be able to translate it to other languages.

What it's the best workaround for this problem?
I was thinking on `StatusToString()` method on the Entity, but I don't know how to access Entities methods using Twig.

Comment: You can create a method getStatusAsString() and use it as such in Twig template: `entity.getStatusAsString()` or `entity.statusAsString`

Comment: Consider making future develops lives much easier by adding a status table m-1 which contains all the possible status' and their names. Then you'll simply need to call product.status.name (or add a __toString returning this->name then product.status in twig alone will suffice), you can then use doctrine/translatable to provide translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 reasonable options.

1.
Within your Product entity you could have

```
public function getStatusName(){
       switch($this->getStatus()){
           case 0:
              return "Deleted";
           case 1:
              return "Active";
           case 2:
              return "Disabled";
       }
}
```

Then within your template you simply need to call

```
{{ product.statusName }}
```

2.
You could consider making future develops lives much easier by adding a status table m-1 which contains all the possible status' and their names.

```
//Product.php
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Status", inversedBy="products")
 */
private $status


//Status.php
 /**
 * @ORM\Column(type="name")
 */
 private $name;

 /**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="product")
 */
 private $products;
```

Then you'll simply need to call:

```
{{ product.status.name }}
```

You could go one step further and add:

```
public function __toString(){
    return (string) $this->getName();
}
```

Then within your template you can simply call:

```
{{ product.status }}
```

Adding traslations to this would be as simple as following the guide provided here: http://atlantic18.github.io/DoctrineExtensions/doc/translatable.html

Personally I'd go with option 2, it helps future proof your code.

I've had to deal far to many times with legacy code with random INT's scattered through the code with no reference to know what each is worth. Some people using 1 for an active record where other parts of the code use 1 for retired.

Using a table to store it all, also means you can reuse the same table for every entity that may ever have a status.

Comment: I really like your second option! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you and no worries. If using it please remember you'll need to setup the rest of your entity eg private $id etc :)